# Low level stream I/O in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I'm trying to find some information about low-level I/O with the `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` streams in Python 3.7, but my Google-fu is failing me.

Basically, I have an interactive application where I want to read raw bytes from the console (i.e. `sys.stdin`) without echoing what has been typed until I write them back to `sys.stdout`. My first attempt was the following, but it echoes what is being typed and the output is not shown until I send an EOF.

```py
while True:
    read_bytes = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
    # do something with the bytes before echo
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(read_bytes)
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
```

I found the following snippet to disable terminal echoing that seems to work, but I still need to read bytes without having to send an EOF.

```py
def enable_echo(fd, enabled):
    (iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc) = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

    if enabled:
        lflag |= termios.ECHO
    else:
        lflag &= ~termios.ECHO

    new_attr = [iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc]
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, new_attr)
```

Am I overthinking how to do this? It feels like there is something obvious I'm missing, or perhaps there is a Python module that does this for me already. Using the raw `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` is not strictly required but it would be nice to be able to switch I/O streams (i.e. a file).

Comment: How do you know when the input is done without receiving an EOF? Are you reading by line? Reading a block of known length? Something else?

Comment: I want to continuously read 1 byte at time, i.e. each key-press should be able to be read individually. It's actually an emulator, so I want each key-press (i.e. written byte) to be fed into the emulated UART without waiting for a linebreak or EOF because this is how serial communication works.

Comment: @tobier have you found a solution? I'm having a similar problem in my Transform Hub, where I want to read streams from http and I can't be sure they're newline terminated. The tooling around it would send me chunks as they come in TCP, but Python ignores this...